# EF 4.4 Code First - Auto generation creating two instances of database

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I recently upgraded from EF 4.3.1 to 4.4 and something odd started happening.  I have touched the code since the upgrade, so I can't say with 100% certainty that it was that which caused this issue.

Anyway, when I blow away the existing database and call Update-Database from the PM console, it creates a database, but with the fully-qualified name of my context.  I.e., MyProject.Data.MyContext.  Previously, it just created a database called MyContext.  I can initialize a bunch of data in the database for testing purposes, but when the app runs, it says there is nothing in the database.

When I go look at the database, I see that now there is another database called MyContext (like in the past).  When I initialize the test data in that database, the app runs just fine and sees the data.

I am overriding the OnModelCreating method.  Basically it looks like this:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {//My modelBuilder stuff.
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);}
```

Not much has changed in this method, so I don't think that is the culprit.  Has anyone encountered this issue before?  Let me know if you want me to post more of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your code to make sure there isn't two classes that are implementing DbContext - I've run into this when using scaffolding.

Open your context, and try setting it up with the connection string explicitly, like:

```
    public myContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
```

Check your web.config to see if anything looks weird with your EF settings and connection strings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried explicitly passing the connection string name to base like you suggested, and it said no connection string with that name could be found in the config file.  I verified that the connection string does exist in the config file, so that is suspicious.  Also, all the settings for EF in my config file were commented out, but it didn't seem to complain about that.  Seems pretty odd.

Comment: You're answer helped me get to the bottom of it, so I marked it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turns out that I needed to blow away my app.config file since I am using EF Code-First.  *I started out with a database first approach*, but then changed it to Code-First.  Once I blew away the app.config file, it worked correctly - only creating one database with the update-database command and using the same database in my code.

Oh, and I was able to set my database name in the context constructor as follows:

```
MyContext() : base("MyDatabase") { }
```